# Multiple commands in Powershell script with Export

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I've been trying to work through this for quite some time.  My ultimate goal is to get the exported report as a single csv sheet.  However, I've been highly unsuccessful.  I then broke it down to export 2 sheets that I can just merge, however, CIM is not playing nice with that at all.  Then my other issue came with not calling from my list properly.

```
$ComputerList = "C:\ps_test\pclastlogon.txt"
$LogPath = "C:\ps_test\Logs"
$LogTime = Get-Date -Format s | foreach {$_ -replace ":", "-"}
$CsvLogonPath = $LogPath+'\RebootStatus-'+$LogTime+'-Logon.csv'
$CsvBootPath = $LogPath+'\RebootStatus-'+$LogTime+'-LastBoot.csv'

Import-Module ActiveDirectory

IF ( -Not (Test-Path -Path $LogPath)) {New-Item -Path $LogPath -ItemType Directory}

$Computers = Get-Content $ComputerList

Foreach ($Computers in $ComputerList) {
Get-ADComputer -Identity $Computers -Properties * -Filter * | Select-Object cn,LastLogonDate,@{LABEL="Last Logon";EXPRESSION={[DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.LastLogon)}} | Export-Csv -Path $CsvLogonPath
}

Foreach ($Computers in $ComputerList) {
Get-CimInstance Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $Computers | Select csname,LastBootUpTime | Export-Csv -Path $CsvBootPath
}
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I recommend looking at the `Foreach-Object` cmdlet instead of the foreach statement.

Answer (score 1):

1. Not to use -filter * -Properties *, its too expensive. Mention the required Properties in `-Properties` and if you are mentioning `-Identity`, `-filter *` is not necessarily required.
2. Wrap `Get-ADComputer` and `Get-CimInstance` in a single `foreach` and create a CustomObject then export to CSV.

[Not Tested]
Fore example:

```
$AllDetails = Foreach ($Computers in $ComputerList) {
          $DetailsfromAD = Get-ADComputer -Identity $Computers -Properties cn,LastLogonDate,LastLogon | Select-Object cn,LastLogonDate,@{LABEL="Last Logon";EXPRESSION={[DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.LastLogon)}}
          $DetailsFromCIM = Get-CimInstance Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $Computers | Select csname,LastBootUpTime 

          $PropertyHash = @{
                           CN               = $DetailsfromAD.CN
                           LastLogonDate    = $DetailsfromAD.LastLogonDate
                          'Last Logon'      = $DetailsfromAD.'Last Logon'
                           csname           = $DetailsFromCIM.csname
                           LastBootUpTime  = $DetailsFromCIM.LastBootUpTime
           }
           New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $PropertyHash
}
```

Export `$AllDetails` to a CSV file

Comment: This is exactly the solution I was going to come down and write. Just create a PSCustomObject with the results of both commands in each loop that gets rolled up into the final object for export to CSV.

Comment: Here's what my export results return

IsReadOnly IsFixedSize IsSynchronized Keys Values SyncRoot Count
FALSE FALSE FALSE System.Collections.Hashtable+KeyCollection System.Collections.Hashtable+ValueCollection System.Object 5

Comment: @DezirdtUzurnaim a small correction added (New-Object)

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess here but after piping I think you need to for-each your command list.  Something like

```
Get-ADComputer -Identity $Computers -Properties * -Filter * | % { Select-Object cn,LastLogonDate,@{LABEL="Last Logon";EXPRESSION={[DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.LastLogon)}} | Export-Csv -Path $CsvLogonPath }
```

But then you will need to do something to append each result instead of just having the last one in `$CSvLogonPath`

Answer (score 0):

A general approach to join two object lists that result from a single source list:

Add the computer name (`$Computers`) from the original computer list (`$ComputerList`) as a primary key in both object lists using `@{Label="ComputerName"; Expression={$Computers}}`:

```
$ADComputers = Foreach ($Computers in $ComputerList) {
    Get-ADComputer -Identity $Computers -Properties * -Filter * | Select-Object @{Label="ComputerName"; Expression={$Computers}},cn,LastLogonDate,@{LABEL="Last Logon";EXPRESSION={[DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.LastLogon)}}
}

$CimInstances = Foreach ($Computers in $ComputerList) {
    Get-CimInstance Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $Computers | Select @{Label="ComputerName"; Expression={$Computers}},csname,LastBootUpTime
}
```

Use the [`Join-Object`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45483110/1701026) function to join the object lists on the `ComputerName`:

```
$ADComputers | Join $CimInstances -On ComputerName | Export-Csv -Path $CsvBootPath
```

You might consider to go easy on this and forget about the primary key and just join the two tables based on the their index:

```
$ADComputers | Join $CimInstances -Using {$LeftIndex -eq $RightIndex}
```

But I recommend against this because if one of your tables is missing a record (e.g. because it doesn't exist the database), the indexes will likely be incorrect aligned.